# Input form field in a return confirm window

Tags: php, html

When you press a button inside a specific html page i've created, you send an email to a specific person. The button is "calling" an other php page (email-specific-client.php)  which has all data stored inside.

```
<a href="email-specific-client.php" id="email"
name="Email" value="Email" class="btn btn-info float-right" style="margin-right: 40px; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbspEmail-Specific-Client</a>
</button>
```

What i want is to create an input field, when you press this button in order to ask to what email should you sent this to. Something similar to return confirm popup window but with a input form field :

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Please Type Client`s Email')" 
href="email-specific-client.php" id="email"
name="Email" value="Email" class="btn btn-info float-right" style="margin-right: 40px; margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbspEmail-Specific-Client</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Where is `<button>`?

Comment: You can try sending the data with an AJAX request using JS.

Comment: You can't put an input in a confirm box. What you're probably looking for is a "modal popup" which is actually contructed from a HTML div and some CSS. There are a billion examples online.